# Background problem in ASP.NET using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm creating a website in Visual Studio 2017, and I want to give it background images and colors.

The problem is that it isn't responding when I'm doing it in the design mode or if I'm using HTML.

Hhere's what I've tried - please tell me what I can do:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 64px;
    }
    .auto-style2 {
        width: 315px;
        height: 60px;
    }
    .auto-style6 {
        color: #C2C5C5;
        background-color: #FF0066;
    }
    .auto-style7 {
        color: #563C24;
        background-color: #FF0066;
    }
    .auto-style8 {
        color: #F6AC2A;
        background-color: #FF0066;
    }
    .auto-style9 {
        color: #302805;
        background-color: #FF0066;
    }
    .auto-style10 {
        width: 178px;
        height: 60px;
    }
    .auto-style11 {
        width: 175px;
        height: 60px;
    }
    .auto-style12 {
        width: 177px;
        height: 60px;
    }
    .auto-style13 {
        background-color: #FF0066;
    }
    .auto-style14 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .auto-style15 {
        background-image: url(wand.jpg);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: note that the images are relative to the document.

Comment: Can you please explain. What do you mean by "relative to the document"                                        ps: I'm a beginner

Comment: Please include the HTML on which the CSS applies. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) **if you use the rendered HTML**, not the ASP.NET code if present.

Comment: you'd be better seeing if it actually works when you run it, the VS designer is not a very accurate guide to the final result, in general. Far better to work with the raw HTML.